# Typing into Safari on iPad extremely slow

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, performance

We have an iPad mini 2 running iOS 9. Ever since upgrading, any text field in Safari is *painfully* slow, generally taking 2 to 4 seconds before responding, and then doing so in fits and jerks. This does not appear to happen anywhere else that I have seen.

I'd like to fix this, but I'm not sure where to start. There do not appear to be any Safari extensions, so it seems to have something with the Safari install itself. Is there any way to do a clean re-install Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only running iOS 9 or 9.1, upgrade to the latest version, iOS 9.2.1. This version improved performance on older devices. If you do happen to be running this version, I would suggest restoring the device and *not* restoring from a backup such as iCloud or iTunes.

Comment: *sigh* I was *sure* I was running 9.2.1, but it was 9.2. The upgrade immediately solve the problem.

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. @MauryMarkowitz

Comment: I should point out it's still slow, just not *as* slow. Useable at least.

Comment: If it continues to be very slow, I would suggest restoring it. @MauryMarkowitz

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings>safari and uncheck open new tabs in background. Sorted.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions